# Drag forward installed Python packages when upgrading

Tags: package-management, python

As somebody who runs multiple webservers each running a set of Django sites, keeping on top of my Python stack is very important. Out of (probably bad) habit, I rely on Ubuntu for a number of my Python packages, including `python-django` and a lot of `python-django-*` extras. The websites require these to run but as long as the package still exists, this isn't an issue. I do this rather than using VirtualEnv (et al) because I *want* Ubuntu to install security updates.

However the Ubuntu repos don't cater for everybody. There are cases where I'll use `pip` or `easy_install` to suck in the latest version of a Python package. When you update Python (as occasionally happens in Ubuntu), you lose all your `pip`-installed packages.

What terrifies me is the deeper I get, the more servers I administer, there's going to be an OS update one day that requires hours and hours of my time running around, testing sites, reinstalling python packages through `pip`. The worst bit of this is potential downtime for client sites though I do test on my development machine (always at Ubuntu-latest) so this should offset some of that worry.

**Is there anything I can do to make sure updates to Python mean the existing, non-dpgk'd Python packages are brought forward?**

That would make sure I always had access to the same packages. I'd still have to test for incompatibilities but it would be a good start.

There's perhaps one better solution: an application that behaved like `apt` and `dpkg` but for interacting with [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/) (where `pip` and `easy_install` get most of their mojo). Something that stored a local list of installed packages, checked for updates like `apt`, managed installing, etc. **Does such a thing exist?** Or is it a rubbish idea?

Comment: Hi Oli. Just out of interest. Did you find another solution over the past several years? What did you end up doing?

Comment: I moved to virtualenv.

Comment: How do you keep all the different virtualenvs up to date?

Comment: There's only two. One I develop with and one I deploy with. If I want to update something I have to update the development system and test every site that uses that package. Then I update production. It's painful but I'm not forced to do it when updating Ubuntu, which is nice.

Comment: Maybe you could add that workflow as an answer? It implies, I guess, that you try to use one and the same virtualenv for all your development. Or do you use different versions of django etc? At present I use a different venv for each development.. maybe that is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding how to keep your Python packages when the system Python is
upgraded: I see two options:

1. You can install non-Ubuntu Python stuff with `easy_install
   --install-dir /usr/local/python` Then you make sure that all your
   webapps include that directory into `sys.path`, for instance by
   including it into PYTHONPATH, or using a directory that is
   automatically included by `site.py` (whose doc states that "Local
   addons go into `/usr/local/lib/python<version>/dist-packages`")
2. You can use virtualenvs, provided you can place all your app data
   and configuration in a directory independent of the code.
   Here's a sketch procedure:

   a. Place all the code-independent stuff into directory
       `myapp-data/`

   b. Create virtualenv `myapp-code.XXX/` (where `XXX` is some
       unique version number, e.g., `date -I`)

   c. Place app code and all dependency packages in `myapp-code.XXX`

   d. `ln -s myapp-code.XXX myapp-code`

   When you have to upgrade, you just repeat steps b. and c. with a
   different revision code YYY, then: stop currently running app,
   symlink `myapp-code` to `myapp-code.YYY`, start app from virtualenv
   `myapp-code.YYY`.  If something goes wrong, you can still roll back to the
   old virtualenv quickly.

Apparently, 2. is more work (but `pip` plus some shell-scripting will
take you a long way towards automating it), but it should also be more
robust and will allow you to concurrently run applications that depend
on different versions of some Python package.

Regarding your question about an `apt-get`-like for Python packages:
`pip` explicitly disallows such a thing, and for a good reason:
package APIs and behavior may change across different versions.
Therefore, if your code runs fine against version X, it may fail when
run with version X+1.  This is exactly what `pip` tries to prevent
with its "freeze" and "requirements list" features.

Of course, the same argument can be applied to any program in a binary
distribution like Ubuntu; indeed, what makes `apt-get` useful is that
Debian and Ubuntu provide a *coordinated release* of interoperable
packages: a lot of effort from the maintainers goes into ensuring that
all Ubuntu packages in the main repositories are compatible.

There is just no such coordinated release of Python packages: each
package is independent and no information is available about what
version of other Python packages are compatible with it.  (This could
possibly be a good addition to PyPI metadata.)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a configuration management system like [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) to run scripts on all servers to keep them all in sync. Your scripts (recipes) can manage the upgrade including automatic testing if the upgrade was successful or broke something.