# preventing pip from removing system packages during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, package-management, python

I have a fairly straightforward Ubuntu (13.04) desktop installation, which comes complete with several Ubuntu-packaged Python utilities -- these live in `/usr/lib/python2.7` and are owned by root. I call these "system" Python packages.

I also do a lot of scientific work with Python and so I have installed tools like numpy, matplotlib, etc. using `pip` -- these live in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` and are owned by me (I `chown`ed `/usr/local` because I'm the only user on this machine). I call these "local" Python packages. I put the local path in front of the system one in my `PYTHONPATH` so that I load local packages preferentially.

Now, I'm trying to upgrade one of the local packages that I installed using `pip`, and `pip` is failing because it wants to uninstall a dependent system package as part of the upgrade process.

I have two questions about this, addressing the problem from each end :

One way to fix this problem is to get `pip` to upgrade my local packages and ignore the system-installed ones (if possible). **Can I prevent `pip` from trying to uninstall a system package during a local package upgrade, but only for one dependency ?**

Another way would be to have `pip` install a newer version of the package, and then use that version to satisfy dependencies in `apt` related tools. **Is there a way to tell Ubuntu that a `pip`-installed package will satisfy an `apt` dependency ?**

(I am familiar with virtualenv, but on this machine I only ever use this one environment, so I'd really like to avoid keeping track of whether I'm working in the correct virtualenv.)

Comment: Even if I'd only use one environment, I would still wrap it in a virtualenv. Your question is not completely clear to me.

Comment: I figured that would be the first answer, so I updated my questions a bit ; hopefully it'll be clearer what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want pip to install or uninstall any dependencies you can use

```
pip install --no-deps package_name
```

Be ware that you are in that case responsible for making sure the different dependencies needed for the package you install are satisfied.

To use it when upgrading a package use:

```
pip install -U --no-deps package_name
```

For a similar problem, cf. [Drag forward installed Python packages when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4898/drag-forward-installed-python-packages-when-upgrading?rq=1)

Comment: I ended up using this in combination with a `virtualenv`. It ended up being simpler to have a way to completely separate my `pip`-installed packages from the system ones.

Comment: That is exactly the same setup I have. You can also look into virtualenvwrapper if you start using different venvs.