# Upgrade python packages with pip: use "sudo" or "--user"?

Tags: python, sudo, pip

I have a question about installing/upgrading Python packages using the tool `pip`.

I can either run

```
sudo pip install -U PACKAGENAME
```

or

```
pip install -U PACKAGENAME --user
```

What is the difference between those two commands and which one should I prefer...

1. on my own machine?
2. in the install script of a python program I publish?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip

Comment: There are a couple ways to call `pip` via `sudo`: either `sudo -H pip install...` or `sudo -H python -m pip install...` (note that `pip` likes to be called using `sudo -H`). The `pip` bundled with `python` is available as of Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later (for Python 3).

Comment: It'd be great (and related to this question) if someone could clarify if `sudo pip` does anything w/ system dependencies as well; e.g., does a `sudo pip` on Ubuntu actually call `apt-get` to install (or remove!) anything?  For instance, if I'm installing `ipython` via `pip` (putting it into `/usr/local` by default), but an older one was already installed via `apt-get` (`/usr/bin`), does my system only work correctly if `/usr/local/bin` is in my path ahead of `/usr/bin`? These issues _seem_ to be resolved at run-time.  Or, does `sudo pip` do anything special at install time?

Comment: @michael_n Not sure, but I strongly believe that `pip` is completely unrelated to `apt`. One does not use the other and vice versa.

Comment: @ByteCommander but pip _does_ seem to uninstall system packages (or so it reports, when installing things); others seem to agree, but this is not clearly documented (as far as I can tell): http://askubuntu.com/questions/333475/preventing-pip-from-removing-system-packages-during-upgrade

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me the only difference is the scheme path.

Using sudo your package will be installed in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

With `--user` they are installed in your `$HOME` directory in:

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

For your own system, I'd say it does not really matter. Use `--user` if you're not a sudoer member.

For code you publish, avoid `--user`.

Comment: Could you explain why to avoid `--user`, please? I only read about [avoiding `sudo`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/4464570) yet...

Comment: @ByteCommander: For a program you publish I'd not make any assumptions of the target directory of the end user. It can be run with root or not. So I'd not mess my install script with commands that would install modules in several locations.

Comment: @ByteCommander I should add (and confirm) that sudo is for modules you trust. If you want to test a new fancy package, try it first with --user.

Comment: my inclination is that this answer is **wrong**.  With ruby, you want that restricted to a user and not to effect the system as a whole.  The same reasoning applies here.  However, I'm not sure, so just making a comment.  Please correct.