# Is it okay to mess around with Python that comes with Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, python3

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and am new to Linux. I know that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS comes with Python 3.4.0. Is it okay if I install pip3 and install packages (e.g. django, numpy, etc.) on it? Can I also upgrade it to Python 3.4.1?

Answer (score 4):

As [I've asked and advocated before](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A449+virtualenv), I'd suggest using a `virtualenv`. It looks like more work but it's actually a ton less in the long run.

- [How can I install Django for Python 3.x?](https://askubuntu.com/a/409595/449) This contains everything you need to get up and running.
- [easy_install/pip or apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/a/21031/449)
- [How to install pip for python 3 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/a/412179/449)
- [Drag forward installed Python packages when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/q/4898/449) really highlights the pain you get into using `pip` with the system's site packages. Don't do it.

Comment: Django 1.6 is not compatible with python 3.4. However, Ubuntu 14.04 comes with Python 3.4. How do I install Python 3.3.5 without overriding the original Python and use virtualenv?

Comment: Hmm.. Yes that's interesting. I think on balance, I'd shoot for Django 1.7 (tracking the dev releases). Can't guarantee that'll be pain-free but it's fairly simple and puts you ahead for upgrading later on.

Answer (score 0):

I use pip on my machine all the time, installing packages globally or locally works just fine. I've never tried upgrading the version of python that ships with ubuntu, though I don't see why you couldn't. Virtualenv is your friend.
You can install pip3 with `apt-get install python3-pip` and then use pip to install whatever from there.