# How can I tidy up the mess that is my Python installations?

Tags: apt, python, python3, cleanup, pip

I had a Ubuntu 12.04 system which I eventually managed to get Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 working together (with `pip` and `pip3`) and Python 3.3 (with `pip3.3`) for good measure.

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and have decided to take advantage of the `python3-pip` package. I've also upgrade my `python3` package to install Python 3.4.

All I really want is to be able to use `python` (`python2`) and `python3` as well as do package management using `pip` and `pip3`. Which of the following files and directories can I delete to make this installation less messy and confusing?

```
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/bin/easy_install3
/usr/bin/easy_install-3.4
/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.3
/usr/bin/python3.3m
/usr/bin/python3.4
/usr/bin/python3.4-config
/usr/bin/python3.4m
/usr/bin/python3.4m-config
/usr/bin/python3-config
/usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python3m-config
/usr/bin/python-config

/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3.3
/usr/lib/python3.4  

/usr/local/bin/easy_install
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.2
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2.7

/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python3.2
/usr/local/lib/python3.3
/usr/local/lib/python3.4
```

Also, both `pip` and `pip3` are currently version 1.5.4, how can I update them both to version 1.5.6 without screwing anything up?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally **leave Ubuntu's Python alone**.
[Use virtualenv (with `--no-site-packages`) for development](https://askubuntu.com/a/482269/449).

It all feels pretty weird and a little stressful when you begin but seriously, not bumping into system conflicts and or having your entire Python stack break when you do a release upgrade... It's a million times nicer.

Some people go for one virtualenv per project. I like to keep mine together because it forces me to maintain old code. I can't let Django 1.1 projects exist because they aren't compatible with my Django 1.5 environment.

The obvious exception to any of this is developing *for* Ubuntu ... but then you really need to rely on Ubuntu-shipped packages (or include libraries in your package).

Comment: Not so simple if you want to use packages like PyQt.

Comment: @Valentas Sure. Not impossible but there are several ways you can cheat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox and you still get a nice local environment.

Comment: @Valentas You can just symlink the PyQt libraries into the virtualenv.