# How to keep python virtualenvs while updating ubuntu?

Tags: python, 20.04, python3, virtualenv

A friend of mine told me that every python virtualenv he had in its ubuntu 18 OS became useless when he upgraded to ubuntu 20, and I think it's because of the new python version (3.8). If anyone could give me some sort of solution for keeping these virtualenvs "alive", I would appreciate it. I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4898/drag-forward-installed-python-packages-when-upgrading) question but it isn't my case (I guess). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) which allows you to quickly install different python versions locally.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
$ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ . ~/.bashrc
$ pyenv install 3.6.9
```

You can easily switch between python versions using:

```
$ pyenv global 3.6.9
```

That should get you back to the python version you need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. The reason is that Python 3.6 and 3.7 are no longer included in the system packages. If you've created a virtual environment for 3.6/ 3.7 using `virtualenv`, it still expects a matching system interpreter. You can install these Python versions via the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6 # and python3.6-venv, python3.6-dev if needed
```

In many cases, this won't suffice: Check `ls -la| grep python3` in your `venv/bin`-directory and you'll see links like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me    16 Mai 10 16:20 python -> /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me     6 Mai 10 16:20 python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me     6 Mai 10 16:20 python3.6 -> python
```

This environment links against the default Python instead of specifically linking against Python 3.6. You'll need to change the base link like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 python
```

Then, the environment should continue to work. I haven't tested it myself though and just upgraded my environments instead.